# Customizing the PnP document search handlebar template in SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, spfx, modern-experience, pnp

I would like to customize PnP search web part so it show results same as we see in default search in sharepoint with document preview and created data and modified data short summary and dividing line after each results

I tried using list layout getting results in very simple format I  have created All results web part which are taking data from drive, external, list item and sites.

Can anyone help me in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all check if any of the available layouts/templates satisfies your requirements:

[image]

**Reference**: [Search Results - Layouts](https://microsoft-search.github.io/pnp-modern-search/usage/search-results/layouts/)

If not, you can create your own custom layout/template from scratch as per your requirements.

Follow this article for detailed steps: [Create your first custom template](https://microsoft-search.github.io/pnp-modern-search/scenarios/create-your-first-custom-template/)

Comment: Thank you but I have different entity types to search in one search result and want different layout for different entity in   want to understand how can we write different condition for different entity in my one custom template

Comment: You must be getting the name of entity type in results. You may need to write handlebar conditions/expressions based on it. Check the extensibility section if it helps: https://microsoft-search.github.io/pnp-modern-search/extensibility/